# Controlling roundness of widget corners from a widget host on Android 12

Tags: android-widget, android-12

The Android 12 [documenatation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/widgets#rounded-corner) says that launchers can control widget corner radii.
It has something to do with the new parameters added in Android 12 - `system_app_widget_background_radius` and `system_app_widget_inner_radius`

So, how do you do this? Is it limited to launchers or any widget host can do it?

Answer (score 2):

It's the responsibility of the host (the launcher), yes.

You can see Launcher3's implementation and logic for whether it should be enabled [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/apps/Launcher3/src/com/android/launcher3/widget/RoundedCornerEnforcement.java;l=76), so to disable you simply make your `@android:id/background` View have `android:clipToOutline="true"`. If you don't have a background View, it should be the widget's background element, so just set the ID as that.

Comment: That is what I did, but then there are Google widgets that come with predefined rounded corners ([opted out](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/apps/Launcher3/src/com/android/launcher3/widget/RoundedCornerEnforcement.java;drc=a750f8cdcab8c244e1b206f5ea004e78f8babcb4;l=71)) So I don't understand why did they put the responsibility of controlling corner roundness on the launcher, but at the same time made all their widgets with a fixed corner radius.